# React: controlled inputs in functional components using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to write a functional component that includes an `<input>`, but I'm getting the "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled." error and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've reduced my code to this, which reproduces the problem:

```
function Input({ value, onChange }) {
    const [text, setText] = useState(value);

    function update(event) {
        setText(event.target.value);
        if (typeof onChange === "function") {
            onChange(event.target.value);
        }
    }

    return (
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={update} />
    );
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to use `useState` here to make this a controlled element—because this is clearly not working :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are most likely not passing in a `value` prop to your `Input` component, which will cause `text` to be `undefined` initially, and when you set the text in `update`, it becomes controlled.

You can change your code to pass in a `value` prop to `Input` every time you use it, or give `value` a default value of an empty string.

```
function Input({ value = "", onChange }) {
    const [text, setText] = useState(value);

    function update(event) {
        setText(event.target.value);
        if (typeof onChange === "function") {
            onChange(event.target.value);
        }
    }

    return (
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={update} />
    );
}
```